# How can Kafka limitations be avoided?

Tags: java, bigdata, business-intelligence, apache-kafka

We're trying to build a BI system that will collect very large amounts of data that should be processed by other components.
We decided that it will be a good idea to have an intermediate layer to collect, store & distribute the data.

The data is represented by a big set of log messages. Each log message has:

- a product
- an action type
- a date
- message payload

System specifics:

- average: 1.5 million messages / minute
- peak: 15 million messages / minute
- the average message size is: 700 bytes (aprox 1.3TB / day)
- we have 200 products
- we have 1100 action types
- the data should be ingested every 5 minutes
- the consumer applications usually need 1-2-3 product with 1-2-3 action types (we need fast access for 1 product / 1 action type)

We were thinking that Kafka would do this job but we encountered several problems.
We tried to create a topic for each action type and a partition for each product. By doing this we could be able to extract 1 product / 1 action type to be consumed.

Initially we had a problem with "too many opened files", but after we changed the server config to support more files we're getting out-of-memory error (12GB allocated / node)
Also, we had problems with Kafka stability. At a big number of topics, kafka tends to freeze.

Our questions:

- Is Kafka suitable for our use-case scenario? Can it support such a big number of topics / partitions?
- Can we organize the data in Kafka in another way to avoid this problems but still to be able to have a good access speed for 1 product / 1 action type?
- Do you recommend other Kafka alternatives that are better suitable for this?

Comment: have you even done a POC for other solutions like flume with HBase or even AMQ/NSQ acting as your MQ?  if it does not work, do you have the capacity to write your implementation on top of netty/mina easily or you think it will way too much time for you.  I know its better to re-use what's already out there

Comment: @alihaider thx for the suggestions we tried HBase but it was slow for our near real time needs as for AMQ its the next one on the list :) and i agree with you its much more efficient to use a solution that's already done than to write your own solution from scratch

Comment: if what you need is closer to real time (I am guessing you are strictly talking about performance and not real time), why don't you look at in-memory datagrids like hazelcast/infinispan (they distribute /replicate data in-memory) and you can query against them from clients (data can be loaded/unloaded from databases as needed)

Comment: @alihaider what we really need is to store in Kafka or something else data every 5 min and consume fast 1 game 1 action per consumer

Comment: these in-memory datagrids have distributed queue and topic implementations in addition to distributed hashmaps/sets etc.

Comment: @alihaider then i'll have a look over them and maybe do a poc thx again for the suggestions

Comment: if you need even more perf, you can use jgroups and its distributed queue.  I think you might be better off with the datargids (because it will save development time).  Make sure you implement serialization - do not rely on java serializable.

Comment: @alihaider jgroups is [at least] order of magnitude slower than kafka, so is hbase, not sure about infinispan/hazelcast though

Comment: @Stephan how do you consume this actions? Can't you intermix actions and then filter out those you don't need on consumer side? `220000` is really tremendous number as kafka keeps 2 files opened for each partition (I'm not even saying about amount of bookkeeping required, it's insane)

Comment: @om-nom-nom - pryvit.  would you like to share the case where that is true for jgroups vs kafka along with test results?  Not questioning what you are saying but would like to know which case you are talking about.

Comment: @om-nom-nom that's exactly our problem that we have a lot of file handles ... the thing is we choose a partition for each product/action because it offers great flexibility from architecture pov. A solution could be only for the products with the most data to have a partition per product/action and in rest to have a partition per product.

Comment: @alihaider sure, though it will take some time to setup repeatable test case (probably a week, maybe a longer -- I'm short on time currently)

Comment: @Stephan well, I asked because there is no special switch (none I know of) to operate in a lightweight mode, thus, you will have to adjust your consuming patterns. If that is not an option for you, switch to a different middleware. We had a similar problem (consuming from kafka in a complicated manner) and **partly** switched to a cassandra. C* is not perfect, e.g. we have freezes in case of GC, but overall it scales good, though we still running kafka in the places where data access patterns are dumb. From the point of performance I think it's close to abovementioned HBase ...

Comment: ... but we've prefered C* as more convenient solution, not because it won from performance POV (background: we're doing data analytics atop of kafka/storm/cassandra with different kinds of realtime reports, 2.5 TB of input events per day, 6 m1.xlarge machines for kafka/C*, if I'm not messing anything)

Comment: @om-nom-nom thx a lot for your input it helps me put things in perspective, we will try some MQ solutions to see how they behave , we tried storm to handle our data processing but it proved slow for our case since pe used grouping on user, can you please give me a like for this C* solution ?

Comment: @Stephan not sure I get what you're saying, namely *used grouping on user* and *give me a like for this C* solution* parts.

Comment: @om-nom-nom in storm we used grouping on user in our sprouts meaning that all actions from a user will go only to a specific bolt... the other matter refers to the solution the you use `we've prefered C* as more convenient solution`  so i was asking for a link to the documentation or something

Comment: @Stephan what is your final solution? i am encountering the same situation that would like to group event into different topic and partion.

Comment: @JianJin the final conclusion was that we need a custom system (due to Kafka limitations and somewhat weak performance) for the job so we started working on that

Comment: It isn't common approach to use large amount of topics in Kafka (even LinkedIn uses not more than 5 topics). Try to partition your data in way you will process it (e.g., by different urgency, department and other), and use the same topics for different streams within the scope of single topic

Comment: @Stephan From the comments, it sounds like you came to a conclusion on this. Is it perhaps worth summing things up in an answer given the up-votes and views on this? It looks like other people are eager for a solution, and sounds like you can probably answer the points in your original question now.

Comment: @JoDouglass good point, i posted an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm posting this answer so that other users can see the solution we adopted.

Due to Kafka limitations (the large no. of partitions which cause the OS to reach almost reach max open files) and somewhat weak performance we decided to build a custom framework for exactly our needs using libraries like apache commons , guava, trove etc to achieve the performance we needed.

The entire system (distributed and scalable) has 3 main parts:

1. ETL (reads the data , process it and writes it to binary files)
2. Framework Core (used to read from the binary files and calculate stats)
3. API (used by many system to get data for display)

As a side note: we tried other solutions like HBase, Storm etc but none live up to our needs.